# Как определить позицию самой старшей единицы в битовом представлении числа?

Tags: c, битовые-операции

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(int args, char** argv[]){
    unsigned b, a;
    int x = atoi(argv[1]), y = atoi(argv[2]);
    unsigned long long num = atoll(argv[3]);
    change(x-1,y-1, num);
}

void change(int x, int y, long long z) {
    //значение байта на позиции x
    long long bx = 0xFF & (z >> (8 * x));
    long long by = 0xFF & (z >> (8 * y));
    //маска содержит нули на позициях x и y
    long long mask = ~(((long long) 0xFF << (8 * x)) | ((long long)0xFF << (8 * y)));
    //обнулили эти позиции
    z &= mask;
    //и заполнили нужными значениями
    z = z | (bx << (8 * y)) | (by << (8 * x));
    printf("%llx\n", z);
}
```

Comment: Непонятно, при чем код к вопросу, и наоборот?...

Comment: А что, если Вы ввели 0? Какой вывод?

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень просто: для числа `N` старшая единица находится на позиции `P`, где `2^P < N < 2^(P+1)`.

Поэтому примерно так: проверяем последовательно степени числа 2, как только результат больше N, то мы нашли P:

```
int res = 1;
int p = 0;
while (res < n){
    p = p + 1;
    res = res * 2; // или res = res << 1
    }
```

Проверку на 0 можете сделать самостоятельно сразу после запроса числа N.

*PS. Нумерация байтов в моем примере начинается с 0. Если нужно начать с 1, то инициализировать p нужно единицей: `int p = 1;`*

*PPS. На работоспособность в С не проверял, возможны небольший синтаксические ошибки.*

Comment: Все, поняла) Спасибо)

Answer (score 3):

Обычно для поиска старшего единичного бита используют функцию, которая возвращает *количество лидирующих нулей*, поскольку очень часто в системе команд процессора существует такая инструкция (например, в X86 это [LZCNT](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/lzcnt)), а компилятор обеспечивает встроенную функцию (например, в GCC это [int __builtin_clz (unsigned int x)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html)).
(см. также [Find first set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set))

Если доступ к таким средствам недоступен (?), то можно воспользоваться одной из достаточно эффективных программных реализаций:

```
#include <stdlib.h>


static inline int _clz4 (uint x) {
  static int n[16] = {4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
  return n[x];
}

static inline int _clz8 (uint x) {
  return x > 0xf ? _clz4(x >> 4) : _clz4(x) + 4;
}
static inline int _clz16 (uint x) {
  return x > 0xff ? _clz8(x >> 8) : _clz8(x) + 8;
}

static inline int clz32 (uint x) {
  return x > 0xffff ? _clz16(x >> 16) : _clz16(x) + 16;
}


// http://embeddedgurus.com/state-space/tag/clz/
#include <stdint.h>

static inline uint32_t CLZ1(uint32_t x) {
    static uint8_t const clz_lkup[] = {
        32U, 31U, 30U, 30U, 29U, 29U, 29U, 29U,
        28U, 28U, 28U, 28U, 28U, 28U, 28U, 28U,
        27U, 27U, 27U, 27U, 27U, 27U, 27U, 27U,
        27U, 27U, 27U, 27U, 27U, 27U, 27U, 27U,
        26U, 26U, 26U, 26U, 26U, 26U, 26U, 26U,
        26U, 26U, 26U, 26U, 26U, 26U, 26U, 26U,
        26U, 26U, 26U, 26U, 26U, 26U, 26U, 26U,
        26U, 26U, 26U, 26U, 26U, 26U, 26U, 26U,
        25U, 25U, 25U, 25U, 25U, 25U, 25U, 25U,
        25U, 25U, 25U, 25U, 25U, 25U, 25U, 25U,
        25U, 25U, 25U, 25U, 25U, 25U, 25U, 25U,
        25U, 25U, 25U, 25U, 25U, 25U, 25U, 25U,
        25U, 25U, 25U, 25U, 25U, 25U, 25U, 25U,
        25U, 25U, 25U, 25U, 25U, 25U, 25U, 25U,
        25U, 25U, 25U, 25U, 25U, 25U, 25U, 25U,
        25U, 25U, 25U, 25U, 25U, 25U, 25U, 25U,
        24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U,
        24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U,
        24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U,
        24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U,
        24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U,
        24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U,
        24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U,
        24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U,
        24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U,
        24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U,
        24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U,
        24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U,
        24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U,
        24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U,
        24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U,
        24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U, 24U
    };
    uint32_t n;
    if (x >= (1U << 16)) {
        if (x >= (1U << 24)) {
            n = 24U;
        }
        else {
            n = 16U;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (x >= (1U << 8)) {
            n = 8U;
        }
        else {
            n = 0U;
        }
    }
    return (uint32_t)clz_lkup[x >> n] - n;
}
```

(функция `CLZ1()` немного быстрее, но занимает больше памяти, чем `clz32()`)

Comment: поправлю, что на вопрос ТС'а ответом будет `sizeof(uint)*CHAR_BIT - 1 - clz(x)`, а не сама `clz()` и я бы ещё добавил, что сама операция равносильна поиску логорифма по основанию 2...  кстати, [есть предложение](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0553r4.html) включить эту операцию в плюсовый стандарт...